# How to preserve the order of multiplication with Cases?

Tags: pattern-matching

i have following expression:

```
Cases[cx[i, k] cx[k, q] a[z, x], _Symbol, 2] // DeleteDuplicates
```

what i expect is to get:

```
{i,k,q,z,x}
```

but i get

```
{z, x, i, k, q}
```

is there any way to preserve the order of multiplication ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Cases[Hold[cx[i, k] cx[k, q] a[z, x]], _Symbol, 3] // DeleteDuplicates
```

The problem was that Mathematica automatically reorders the order of multiplication in a product when you evalute it. The `Hold` prevents Mathematica from evaluating.

Comment: u changed 2 to 3 because of Hold ? now your head is Hold right?

Comment: yes, since it wraps the expression you needed to increase the depth by one.

Comment: very nice and clever.